# Htaccess if HTTP_Host then send 403

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, http-host

Exist a way in Htaccess to say If HTTP_HOST = my.subdomain.com Then block access (403) for the files .php and .html?

I want that the only files accessible throug my subdomain are Images.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.subdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(php|html)$ - [L,F]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.subdomain\.com$
RewriteRule \.(php|html)$ - [NC,F]
```